# In Netbeans, is there a function where I can set a inactive breakpoint on a variable, the breakpoint only activates when variable value changes?

Tags: debugging, variables, netbeans, breakpoints

I'm currently debugging using the Netbeans debugger. I was just wondering if there is a function where I can set a inactive breakpoint on a variable, the breakpoint is only activated when the value of the variable changes?

Comment: Im not that experienced with the Netbeans  IDE, but if you're using beans, you could set a breakpoint on the Setter of this bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it depends on what language are you using. Invoke `Debug` from main menu and then `New Breakpoint`. There you can select e.g. Java for language and will have a plenty of ways/conditions on how to specify breakpoint (including field modifications).

Here is a simple ilustration:

Sample code:

```
public class JavaApplication4 {

public static int something = 2;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i); // this is line #19
        something++;
    }

 } 
}
```

And here are 2 screenshots with possible breakpoints:
[image]
[image]

Comment: i'm writing in java at the moment, could you please go into a bit more detail as how it could be achieved? Thanks again for your help!